MacOS15 выбрать дисплей для открытия приложения через IDE jetbrains
При компиляции приложений например в goland или webstorm по кнопке "Run" выполняется скрипт компиляцией приложения (и возможно gui приложения)
Как сделать открытие этих окон на втором дисплее выполняя Run на первом?
PS: На linux достаточно поставить переменную $DISPLAY=1 перед выполнением скрипта, так же обратил внимание что терминал и gui открывается строго на дисплее на котором открыта ide, игнорируя дисплей по умолчанию 0
